# How to properly mock a function that is imported in a package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I try to test a package that I created and for that I need to mock subprocess.Popen. I want to do this with the patch decorator but I can't specify the right target. I keep getting errors that the attribute doesn't exists in the class.

The structure of my project is like this:

```
.
|- package
|   |- __init__.py
|   |- package.py
|- tests
|   |- test_script.py
```

```py
__init__.py

from package.package import package
```

```py
package.py

from subprocess import Popen


class package:

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "bar"

    def echo_cmd(self):
        p = Popen("test.bat", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        p.wait()
        x = p.communicate()
        return x
```

```py
test_script.py

import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

import package


class TestADBHelper(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.test = package.package()


    @patch("package.Popen")
    def test_connect_to_device_not_connected(self, mock_popen):
        """test if a device can be connected"""
        process = mock_popen.return_value
        process.returncode = 0
        process.communicate.return_value = "foo"
```

I want to mock the output of Popen. I tried different ways of importing and defining the target of the mock but I keep getting errors like:

```
AttributeError: <module 'package' from 'C:\\Users\\***\\Documents\\mock_test\\package\\__init__.py'> does not have the attribute 'Popen'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two things called package and you're mocking the wrong one.

```
@patch("package.package.Popen")
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I tried that but I still get the error: `E           AttributeError: <class 'package.package.package'> does not have the attribute 'Popen'`

Comment: marked this as the answer. The problem with my script was that all the files had the same name. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out :-) It all became clear when I change the names of all the files to package1, package2 and package3. Then the answer above works as expected:

```py
@patch("package1.package2.Popen")
```

Somehow Python always imports the class if the name of the file is the same as the class. So that was the reason it was not able to find "Popen"

Comment: Maybe you are thinking in Java. In Python module names are usually in lowercase and classes in CamelCase. And functions and methods in snake_case(). So that would never happen. See the Python [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names).